# Will using form.hide many times cause problems with memory, etc

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I have a windows form that is used a picture viewer from inside a software application.  User selects something and hits a tool which prompts the form. When they select another item to view another image, another form window is displayed and I use the following to hide the previous form.

My question is this going cause a memory issue or anything?  Lets say maybe 50 forms get opened and hidden during a user's viewing session.

```
private void ShowImageViewer()
{
    FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
    foreach (Form frm in fc)
    {
        if (frm.Visible)
        {
            frm.Hide();
        }
    }
    ImageViewer viewer = new ImageViewer(this, parcelID);
    viewer.Show();
    viewer.Focus();   
}
```

Comment: If the user selects image A, then selects image B and then selects image A again, are there three forms created or just two? In other words, is a new form created every time an image is selected? I ask, because this will determine if you should `.Hide()` or `.Close()` the forms.

Comment: Try it out to see for yourself.  Are you eventually showing the other forms again, or are you creating forms and then hiding them when they'll never actually be shown again?  If they're truly "done" just close them.

Comment: Why you do not simply replace the picture in the same form? Every time you create an istance of a new form, your memory consuption will increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that yes, it will cause problems with memory, because you will not be releasing the memory allocated to the form by simply just calling `.Hide()` on the form.

The real issue is the creation of a new form for every image selected by the user. You will eventually run into a memory issue, because you will have potentially hundreds of forms or more depending on how the user uses the system.

Either call `.Close()` on the form when the user selects a new image or re-use the same form and update the image displayed in the `ImageViewer` object.